# Facebook PHP API v.2.10 How to Extract birth date

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This might be a simple thing, but I' m missing out on something. I'm trying to get a birth date out of Facebook Login, when user logs on to my app. I've got it all set up, and actually I'm nearly there.

Once successfully logged on, I'm using getGraphUser() function on the response object to extract data, like this:

`$user_profile = $response->getGraphUser();`

User birthday is returned as a separate object within the array. When var_dumped `var_dump($user_profile['birthday'])`, it looks like this:

`object(Facebook\GraphNodes\Birthday)#19 (5) { ["hasDate":"Facebook\GraphNodes\Birthday":private]=> bool(true) ["hasYear":"Facebook\GraphNodes\Birthday":private]=> bool(true) ["date"]=> string(26) "1983-11-18 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(11) "Europe/Riga" }`

So, like I said, i'm very close. But not exactly there. Problem is - I cannot get the 'date' field out of this. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: did you checked date('Y-m-d', strtotime($user_profile['birthday']->date))

Comment: Yes, @pravindot17, var_dump($user_profile['birthday']->date) returns NULL

Comment: FYI: Don't expect that to always be a full date - depending on the user's privacy settings, you might get month and date only.

Comment: Yup, thx - have been prepared for that, according to documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this because you need to date object for retrieve:

Use the DateTime object's format method:

```
$user_profile->getBirthday()->format('m/d/Y');
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

if i understood facebook documentation correctly after using getGraphUser you should use $user_profile->getBirthday(). Which should according to documentation return birthday as a datetime.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphNode/5.0.0#user-instance-methods

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, $user_profile->getBirthday() returns exactly the same thing as $user_profile['birthday'], which is where I'm at already. Apparently, the documentation provided by Facebook isn't exactly correct.